# Can the ROOT element in a select statement using FOR XML PATH be set using a variable?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a query that creates an xml file. Currently, I have the ROOT element hard-coded.  I would like to use a variable value to set this root element value but substituting the hard-coded string with the variable throws a syntax error of `expecting a string`.  This is the select statement:

```
DECLARE @SelectResults XML
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(100) 
SELECT @DatabaseName = DB_NAME();

    SET @SelectResults =
    ( 
    SELECT...query results here...
    FOR XML PATH(''),
    ROOT(@DatabaseName) --when this is set to 'DatabaseName' it works
    )
```

Can I use a variable in the function `ROOT()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the replacement in a separate replace acting on the XML output:

```
DECLARE @SelectResults XML
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(100) 
SELECT @DatabaseName = DB_NAME();

    SET @SelectResults =
    replace( 
        SELECT...query results here...
        FOR XML PATH(''),
        ROOT('ROOT_ELEMENT') --when this is set to 'DatabaseName' it works
    ), 'ROOT_ELEMENT>',@DatabaseName+'>' )
```

Comment: Hi, as written below John Cappelettis answer I like this approach (voted up both of you), but you should replace `ROOT_ELEMENT>` rather than `<ROOT_ELEMENT` as you want to replace the closing tag too... And - just to mention this - one should choose a string which will  - for sure! - not be an element's name somewhere else :-)

Comment: Whups, you're absolutely right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: THANKS!  That worked.  Had to use the `REPLACE` function because the stored procedure has to work with SQL Server 2008 and `CONCAT` is not available in that version.

Comment: This works for me, but in my case, I have to break it into 2 replace functions because I am using a namespace at the root node; therefore, 'ROOT_ELEMENT>' can't exist at opening. The first replace takes care of the opening tag and the second, closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little cheat using concat()

> **Create some sample data**

```
Declare @SomeTable table (id int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @SomeTable values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@gmail.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@gmail.com')
```

---

> **The SQL**

```
Declare @SelectResults XML = concat('<',DB_NAME(),'>',(Select * from @SomeTable for XML Path),'</',DB_NAME(),'>') 
Select @SelectResults
```

> **Returns**

```
<Chinrus-Dev>
  <row>
    <id>1</id>
    <First_Name>John</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
    <EMail>john.smith@gmail.com</EMail>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>2</id>
    <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
    <EMail>jane.doe@gmail.com</EMail>
  </row>
</Chinrus-Dev>
```

Comment: Although more wordy than my `REPLACE` answer, I like this better because it does not rely on `ROOT_ELEMENT` never appearing in the actual XML.

Comment: @RossPresser Full Disclosure... My first thought was REPLACE .  That said, I watch for Shnugo.  His work with XML is always the high water mark.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti *high watermark*, thx for this *grin* ! I must admit that I did not even think of this, as I do not like to build XML with string concatenation. But I must admit, that both approaches (`REPLACE` and yours) are more straight forward then mine... As I'm a knight of *ad-hoc-SQL* as well I dislike dnyamic SQL just as I dislike XML via string methods. In this case I'd favour yours...

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this *ad-hoc*

This

```
SELECT 'test'
FOR XML PATH('x'),ROOT('y')
```

leads to

```
<y>
  <x>test</x>
</y>
```

But this is not allowed

```
DECLARE @root NVARCHAR(MAX)='z';
SELECT 'test'
FOR XML PATH('x'),ROOT(@root) <-- error!
```

### dynamic SQL

You might build the statement dynamically

```
DECLARE @root NVARCHAR(MAX)='z';

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
'SELECT ''test''
FOR XML PATH(''x''),ROOT(''' + @root + ''')'
);
EXEC(@cmd);
```

leads to

```
<z>
  <x>test</x>
</z>
```

But - as always - dynamic SQL has some heavy draw backs...